# Download file from site via addon to local disc space and then save any changes back to the site

Tags: internet-explorer, add-on

I have question.

I want create a add-on for Internet Explorer 11 what will be capable to:

1. Download file from site where user has permission to download it (is login / has session)
2. Save that file in local PC
3. Open it in default program (user can edit it, save)
4. This new file or changes will save back to the site.

It is possible? Can add-on manage or have a managed space in local PC? Thank you for any advice. I have read something from developers google web fundamentals and few sites with tables about supported technologies by browser. Somewhere IE has many unsupported technologies compare with other browser so I am not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, IE Add-ons are apps that Internet Explorer uses to interact with web content like videos and games, then improve the functionality or user experience for the browser itself, and it is not able to perform the operations outside the browser. So, for your requirement, I suggest you could add these operations on your website, you could download it to the local side, after editing, re-upload to your web site.

Comment: I thought but as you can see on this PDF some of web application have this functionality (example: [link](https://www.eintranet.net/data/Editace_souboru_a_ulozeni_primo_v_eIntranetu.pdf)). There you can just click on button, then chrome ask you if you want open it with associated app, then its open with microsoft excel for example and after click on save, processing of saving begin automatically or something just happend. I have no idea how they did that.

Comment: Also have no idea about how they did that.

Comment: Now, I understand. They used WebDav protocol.